# App insights: how can i get first 'details' column in the 'problemId' group

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I have this query a count by problemId of the exceptions in App Insights:

```
// exception count by problem ID
let start=datetime("2018-01-09T14:17:00.000Z");
let end=datetime("2018-01-10T14:17:00.000Z");
let timeGrain=5m;
let dataset=exceptions
// additional filters can be applied here
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| where client_Type == "PC" ;
dataset
| project problemId, cloud_RoleName, itemCount, details 
| summarize count_=sum(itemCount) by problemId, cloud_RoleName, stacktrace_ = (tostring(details))
// calculate exception count for all exceptions
| union(dataset
| summarize count_=sum(itemCount)
| extend problemId="Overall")
| order by count_ desc
```

I would also like to include the stacktrace, but I only want to get the first 'details' column for a group of 'problemId'. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a first() operator for summarize, but you could use the `any()` operator if you just want one (random) value for each group.

like

```
 | summarize count_=sum(itemCount), any(details) by problemId, ...
```

"first" would generally imply some kind of order within the groups, so i'm not sure there's an easy way to do that without making the query a lot more complicated.

see: https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Aggregation-functions/any()

Answer (score 1):

**arg_min()** and **arg_max()** can do the trick. First parameter is a field to sort the group on. Second and subsequent parameters are fields to return.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-min-aggfunction